# Java program compile using Apache Tika library - dependencies

Tags: java, maven, ant, apache-tika

I'm trying to compile a simple Java program that uses Tika.

I have the following in the program:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;
import org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.OOXMLParser;
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
```

I have downloaded Tika from [here](https://tika.apache.org/download.html) onto my Windows 7 PC
I have pointed to these Tika jar files using environment variable CLASSPATH

However when I compile the program (using `javac myprogram.java`) there are lots of errors as there are dependent packages required.

Is there a download that has all required packages in one place?
Can I use ANT or maven to get the dependent packages?
Is there a simple guide to ANT or maven?

At the least it needs:

- tika-app-1.10.jar
- poi-3.13.jar
- poi-examples-3.13.jar
- poi.excelant-3.13.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.13.jar
- poi-ooxml-schemas-3.13.jar
- poi-scratchpad-3.13.jar
- openxml4j-1.0-beta.jar
- xmlbeans-2.6.jar

Answer (score 2):

you can use eclipse or any other IDE to make a maven project. 
In the pom.xml add the following dependencies:-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.16</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tika/tika-parsers -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
    <version>1.16</version>
</dependency>
```

Please look below links if it helps you:-

https://wiki.jasig.org/display/UPM32/Creating+a+Simple+Maven+Project

http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-java-project-with-maven/